# Change table name related to entity model

Tags: entity-framework

I have some data in my database in a table called "Test".
I've made a duplicate of that table called "CopyTest".

If i change:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IISLog>()
    .ToTable("Test");
```

to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IISLog>()
    .ToTable("CopyTest");
```

I get an error saying:

> context has changed since the database was created. Consider using
>   Code First Migrations to update the database

How can i stop this from showing? It's just a table name change :)

Answer (score 1):

- **Solution 1**:

Delete First Migration and than try:

```
Add-Migration <migration-name>
```

Then open Migration file and change Table Name Manually. After that:

```
update-database -verbose
```

*If it not works.*

- **Solution 2**:

Try to delete Migration History from **SQL server Management studio** .

Reference URL - [Resetting Entity Framework Migrations to a clean Slate](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jan/13/Resetting-Entity-Framework-Migrations-to-a-clean-Slate)

Answer (score 1):

Migrate to the initial DB
with

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:"name_of_migration"
```

then update to your current state:

```
Update-Database
```

if necessary add your migration again:

```
Add-Migration TableNameUpdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new migration using `add-migration Rename_Test_To_CopyTest`

Then, in the resulting file, use the `RenameTable` method:

```
public partial class Rename_Test_To_CopyTest : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        RenameTable("dbo.Test", "dbo.CopyTest");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        RenameTable("dbo.CopyTest", "dbo.Test");
    }
}
```

Then use `update-database` as usual.